# Is it possible to get filename where code is called in Golang?

Tags: file, go

I was able to get the full path of the current directory, Now I would like to create a function that will read or get the filename where the code is executed. I am able to get the filename but it is return the original filename where the code is written :

```
func GetFileName() string {
    _, fpath, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)
    if !ok {
        err := errors.New("failed to get filename")
        panic(err)
    }
    filename := filepath.Base(fpath)
    // remove extension
    filename = removeExtension(filename)
    return filename + ".log"
}
```

What I want to do is getting the current fileName where the code is executed like :

I created `app.go` :

```
package my

function getCurrentFileName() string {
    // some code here that will return the filename where this code is executed.
}
```

and then when I call `getCurrentFileName()` in a different file like `hello.go` in a different location. it will return `hello.go`.

I have been stuck here for a while and looking for an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically this is what you tell / pass to [`runtime.Caller()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller): the number of stack entries to skip before returning an entry.

If you pass `0` as in your code, that means return the stack entry where `runtime.Caller()` is called (where *you* called `runtime.Caller()`). Passing `1` will skip your function, and return the function that called your function:

```
pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
if ok {
    fmt.Printf("Called from %s, line #%d, func: %v\n",
        file, line, runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name())
}
```

Example calling a function that contains this (`subplay.A()` in my example):

```
 7   func main() {
 8      // Comment line
 9      subplay.A()
10   }
```

Output:

```
Called from /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go, line #9, func: main.main
```

We see that the code prints that `play.go` called our function at line #9, from the function `main()` of the `main` package.

Answer (score 1):

This helper function can give those information:

```
func Here(skip ...int) (string, string, int, error) {
    sk := 1
    if len(skip) > 0 && skip[0] > 1 {
        sk = skip[0]
    }
    var pc uintptr
    var ok bool
    pc, fileName, fileLine, ok := runtime.Caller(sk)
    if !ok {
        return "", "", 0, fmt.Errorf("N/A")
    }
    fn := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    name := fn.Name()
    ix := strings.LastIndex(name, ".")
    if ix > 0 && (ix+1) < len(name) {
        name = name[ix+1:]
    }
    funcName := name
    nd, nf := filepath.Split(fileName)
    fileName = filepath.Join(filepath.Base(nd), nf)
    return funcName, fileName, fileLine, nil
}
```

The `skip` parameter is the number of caller frames that we need to go up (the chain of callers).