# Show original source line when wrapping testing.T.Errorf()

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm writing some test for a Go module. A lot of it is checking that functions return the correct values. This is a simple example for what I'm currently doing:

```
package foo

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

func Foo() int {
    return 3
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    expected := 4
    actual := Foo()

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(actual, expected) {
        t.Errorf("actual=%v, expected=%v", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

A single test might contain a many such equality checks. Duplicating these 6 lines for each check makes the tests hard to read and error-prone to write (from what I've experienced the past few days). So I thought I'd make an `assertEquals()` function that wraps the whole logic similar to what other testing frameworks provide (e.g. in [JUnit's `org.junit.Assert`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html)):

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    assertEqual(t, 4, Foo())
}

func assertEqual(t *testing.T, actual interface{}, expected interface{}) {
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(actual, expected) {
        t.Errorf("Assertion failed: %v != %v", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

The problem now is that `Errorf()` will obviously not show the line where `assertEqual()` is called but the call to `Errorf()` inside of `assertEqual`:

```
=== RUN   TestFoo
    foo_test.go:28: Assertion failed: 4 != 3
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
```

Is there a way to fix that, e.g. by showing the whole stack trace instead of only the location of the call to `Errorf()`?

Or is there a better way to avoid repeating those lines of code to check the return value of a function?

Comment: Use testing.T.Helper() .

Comment: Volker: Thanks for the pointers! Sadly, in my experience, table-based tests also reduced readability because the additional data flow that needs to be considered when reading the test (member usage on test instance -> position of member in anonymous type -> column in test data -> find right row based on other hints in the output etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`t.Helper()`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Helper):

> Helper marks the calling function as a test helper function. When printing file and line information, that function will be skipped. Helper may be called simultaneously from multiple goroutines.

So your helper function becomes:

```
func assertEqual(t *testing.T, actual interface{}, expected interface{}) {
    t.Helper()
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(actual, expected) {
        t.Errorf("Assertion failed: %v != %v", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestFoo
    prog.go:13: Assertion failed: 4 != 3
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
FAIL
```

where `prog.go:13` in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HW2iZmEV7lV) is the line in the main test target *that calls* `assertEqual` instead of `t.Errorf` within it.

This will only change the file line in the testing output. If you actually want the full stack trace, you can use `runtime.Caller` as mentioned in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218715/is-it-possible-to-get-filename-where-code-is-called-in-golang) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212985/is-it-possible-get-information-about-caller-function-in-golang) threads.